# Saving API Keys on local.properties File to avoid Version Control Checking-In

Tags: android, version-control, build.gradle

I really need to find out how to save API Keys to avoid exposing sensitive keys on public repos.

Most online tutorials advise using **`local.properties`** file to save API Keys but I see a disclaimer at the top of the `local.properties` file - ***Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!***

[image]

I need to generate a **`buildConfigField`** to access the key on the main source code; this is the code that I have on my `build.gradle` app file for *Kotlin DSL.*

```
defaultConfig{ ...
val properties = Properties()
        val apiKey: String

        val localPropertiesFile = project.rootProject.file("local.properties")
        apiKey = if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            properties.load(localPropertiesFile.inputStream())
            properties.getProperty("API_KEY") ?: ""
        } else {
            System.getenv("API_KEY") ?: ""
        }

        buildConfigField(
                "String",
                "API_KEY",
                "\"$apiKey\""
        )
... }
```

On the idea of using `local.properties` to save api keys file the [docs](https://developer.android.com/build) disagree:

> Caution: The local.properties file is reserved for properties specific
> to the Android Gradle plugin. Putting your own values in this file can
> cause problems. If you need to define your own local properties,
> [create a separate properties file and manually load it.](https://developer.android.com/build/gradle-tips#remove-private-signing-information-from-your-project)

Out of sheer curiosity, I went ahead and saved the key inside the local.properties file - the app built fine but the buildConfigField returned an *Empty String*.

[image]

Who knows how to go about this in a safe recommended way?

Comment: FWIW, your question is all about `local.properties`, but your code is referring to `gradle.properties`: `project.rootProject.file("gradle.properties")`. Personally, I just use a separate properties file, independent from any that Gradle or the Android Gradle Plugin use for their own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that mishap, I have edited the code. I like the idea of using a separate properties file. I will post an answer using this approach. Thanks Mate

Answer (score 1):

Do not save them in local.properties. As you mentioned, the file can be erased. Also, if you need such keys in several projects, you have to keep adding the same values, and it will be useless for CI. Instead of that, add them to your environment and read them from there. The same approach is valid on a CI server (like jenkins), and it will be a bit safer.

Reading an environment value from gradle:

```
    var auth = if(System.getenv("your_key")!=null){
        println("api key is present!")
        System.getenv("your_key")
    } else {
        println("api key is absent. Set it manually and make sure to not commit it.")
        ""
    }
```

Comment: Android Studio won't carry over environment variables from the host environment, last I checked. For values that *only* are needed on CI, this approach seems fine, but it may be problematic for values that are needed both for IDE-based builds and CI.

Comment: Actually, it has access to everything loaded before starting it up. If you add an environment variable or change the path afterwards, you have to close and start AS again.

Comment: If true, that's a departure from past behavior. Android Studio would always run Gradle builds in a separate process that lacked the environment variables available to the Studio process itself. I'm certainly hoping you're correct, because the older behavior was a serious pain in various body parts.

Comment: I'm not sure since when it became possible, but I've been reading environment variables from gradle files in IDEA and AS for a while, maybe since 2019

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) on comments, the easiest way is to create a separate `properties file`.

**Step 1:**
Create `apikeys.properties` file (*you can use your preferred file name as long as it has .properties file extension*) in your *project's root directory* and add your API key:

```
API_KEY = "xyz"
```

**Step 2**: Add the created `.properties` file on `.gitignore file` to avoid its tracking by your version control.

```
local.properties
gradle.properties
apikey.properties
```

Make sure you don't also accept VC's dialogue prompt to add the `.properties` file to staging.

**Step 3:** Inside `build.gradle.kts` file ( i.e. *inside the Android  block*) you can load the key-value properties from the `.properties` file and access them as follows:

```
android { ...

 defaultConfig { ...

    //load the values from .properties file
      val keystoreFile = project.rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
      val properties = Properties()
      properties.load(keystoreFile.inputStream())
    
    //return empty key in case something goes wrong
      val apiKey = properties.getProperty("API_KEY") ?: ""
```

Above code loads the API key from`.properties` file and adds it as a  **`BuildConfig class'`** constant for both release and debug build types.

BuildConfig class is *automatically generated* by Gradle plugin during the build process, it contains various constants and flags that can be accessed in your Android code.

**Step 4:** Specify the **`buildConfigField() function`** - buildConfigField (...) allows us to define custom fields in the `BuildConfig class`. This fxn is useful for *injecting* config values such as API keys etc. It takes 3 args - **Type** (in this case our good-old String), **Name** as specified on `.properties` file and **Value** which is our loaded api key.

```
val apiKey = properties.getProperty("API_KEY") ?: ""

        buildConfigField(
                type = "String",
                name = "API_KEY",
                value = apiKey
        )
```

**Step 5:** Access the BuildConfig class constant on your main source code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        //call BuildConfig to access its API_KEY Constant
        val apiKey = BuildConfig.API_KEY
        Log.i("tag", apiKey)
```

This way, when you push your code into a public repo it won't leak `.properties file` which has your classfied info out there. However, you will still have access to the api keys locally.

Cheers.